# Using bitcoinlib created wallet on exchanges

Tags: bip32-hd-wallets, coinbase.com

I am trying to get familiar with crypto trading, and I know enough Python to be dangerous. Including the ability to created HD wallets using bitcoinlib. My question is, can I use my bitcoinlib created HD wallet(s) to trade on an established exchange e.g. Coinbase? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you do, if you generate valid addresses. I still recommend you use a well known and tested wallet instead, like Bitcoin Core it self, Electrum or Sparrow.